# Converting curl cmd to jQuery $.ajax() in javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a api call with jquery ajax, I have curl working for the api, but my ajax is throwing HTTP 400 error
The current command form this official api website is

```
$ curl -i -H "X-Auth-Token: UUID" -X GET "https://api.apility.net/baddomain/google.com"
```

I tried this but it is not working. I am not familiar with curl and ajax and need help fixing this code

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.apility.net/baddomain/hackthissite.org',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
         xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", "APIKEY");
    }, success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
```

})

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try to set processData: false,and type:"GET"

Comment: I tried it and it still shows this error:                api.apility.net/baddomain/google.com:1 GET https://api.apility.net/baddomain/google.com 404

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "https://api.apility.net/baddomain/google.com",
    headers:{
          'X-Auth-Token':'api',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
```

});

After searching on internet for hours finally get it working. This might help someone down the road.

Comment: You don't need `contentType` for a `GET` request

Comment: Good catch. I am still gonna leave it this way so that it is clear for people.